# Make a unknown number of URL requests asynchronously in Swift

Tags: asynchronous, recursion, swift2, closures, tree-traversal

I need to traverse a tree with an unknown number of nodes by making asynchronous URL requests. My current approach looks like this:

```
class Parent {

    var foo: String
    var id: Int
    var children: [Child]?

    func loadChildren() {

        for child in self.children {
            self.getAllChildren(child)
        }

    }

    func getAllChildren(current: Child) {
        current.load() {(success) in
            if (success) {
                if let children = current.children {
                    for child in children {

                        self.getAllChildren(child)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Child {

    var bar: String
    var id: Int
    var children: [Child]?

    func load(success: (Bool) -> ()) {

        // Load from API and initalize values

    }

}
```

The problem with my current approach above is that I don't known when the loading has finished. I don't care if some children fail to load, but i need to make UI updates when all children (and their children) of an parent have been loaded.

I looked into various approaches like promises and dispatch groups but i'm struggling to get it work. I'm using Swift 2 and ideally the parent would have a function like this:

```
func loadChildren(success: (Bool) -> ()) {
 // do stuff
}
```